# enviar hashtags em colunas diferentes no banco de dados mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de inserir cada palavra "hashtag" em uma coluna da tabela, estou usando esse exemplo:

```
    <form name="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">

    <input name="hashtag`" type="text"/>

    <input type="submit" value="enviar"/>

    </form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST)){

    $hashtag = $_POST['hashtag'];

        $ext = implode(",",$hashtag`);
        var_dump($ext);

        /*resultado da impressão:
        string '#tag1,#tag2' (length=20)
        */

                $insert = DB::getConn()->prepare('INSERT INTO `table` SET `hashtag`=?');
                return $insert->execute(array($ext)) ? 1 : 0;

    }
```

No Banco de dados mysql resultou

```
         id|1|hashtag|#tag1,#tag2
```

Eu gostaria que cada palavra fosse inserida em uma coluna:

```
         id|1|hashtag|#tag1
         id|2|hashtag|#tag2
```

Comment: Queres inserir numa coluna diferente ou numa nova linha? tens colunas diferentes para cada hash?

Comment: @Sergio , sim eu gostaria que cada palavra ser inserida separadamente em cada coluna da tabela ex: #tag1 na primeira, #tag2 na segunda

Comment: E essas colunas têm nomes? Nesse caso tens de ter um numero finito/estático de colunas e tags, ou seja uma tag para cada coluna. Ou queres inserir uma tag por linha?

Comment: Não use o implode. faça um foreach no $hashtag e um insert pra cada um. Se a tabela suportar, pode usar transactions para garantir a integridade. Se usar funções nativas, basta um `prepare` para economizar dados na comunicação do banco (PDO por padrão apenas simula os _prepared statements_, perdendo esta vantagem, mas o mysqli faz nativo)